# Armbian update failing - Dec 2017 - unable to lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Tags: debian, apt, armbian

We'v got a strange problem. We have multiple bootable Armbian (including 5.25 and 5.30). These are of course not the newest, but we would update them immediately after installation with the usual `apt-get upgrade`, run from a sudo'd script. This image and this script did not change.

2 weeks ago we last tried this without any problems. Late last week and now we're seeing `apt-get upgrade` fail on multiple devices, run from multiple base images, all with the same error message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable).
```

There are existing questions about it, suggesting to manually remove the file (doesn't help us) and to check if there are multiple processes running (no, this is a single script, and it fails in the first `apt-get` command.)

I suspect the problem is in a repository as that is the only common factor I have been able to identify in all failure cases, and because it's also the only factor that has changed since 2 weeks ago. I just don't understand how that breaks the local `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` file.

Answer (score 0):

**Armbian** performs an automated update in the background just before the system starts. You only need to wait some minutes to do a manual `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. The time the update takes may vary depending your connection, microSD card speeds, ... So check many times till the process is done.